# Executing GET API in Swagger UI not showing response body for status code 500

Tags: rest, swagger, swagger-ui, internal-server-error

I am executing a GET request in swagger-ui with two query parameters.
On Execution, there is a **500 Internal Server Error** Which is expected.
But the swagger UI only displays this:
[image]
It doesn't display the response body, but when I use Postman for the same GET request, I can see it. Not sure if it's the default behavior for 5xx errors or if it can be configured in the Swagger.